# How many queries are normal to execute on a WP site?

Tags: query, cache

I use the following PHP code in my theme's footer.

```
<?php echo get_num_queries(); ?> queries in <?php timer_stop(1); ?> seconds.
```

Then I realized that about 140 to 210 queries are executed for each page.
Is it normal or not?  I use a caching plugin, does it help?

I'm using a shared hosting and *sometimes* (not always) I get about 20 visitors in a second.

Comment: That is too much. Generally anything above 50 is getting way to much depending on your page. You should download Query Monitor plugin and check where all of this is coming from and then take it from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's not "normal", but it's above typical.

The common minimum of queries would go like:

- main query (set of posts)
- functionality (menus, widgets, etc)
- data (terms and such)

On a WP test data that would make something under 50 queries on home page. With object cache it will fall under 10 on repeat visits.

Without knowing your set up — yes, it is likely that you are requesting too many things and/or not caching results optimally.

However some sites *need* to query a lot of things to, well, perform their function.

Roughly I would recommend to:

- dump queries and examine *what* are they (Query Monitor plugin would be a start)
- add Object Cache back-end to server, see if it makes a difference (but it's a good idea to have in *any* case)
- consider manual or semi-automated caching for code which makes queries (full page and/or fragment cache)